# MySQL FullText in Boolean mode: searching keywords that contain '+' as part of the string

Tags: mysql, sql, full-text-search, mariadb

I have looked at dozen 'similar' questions, without luck. I understand that `+` attached to a keyword in FULLTEXT in BOOLEAN mode has a special meaning,
however, what if our keyword(s) actually contain `+` symbol as a suffix part of the text/string. How can we still use FULL-TEXT search and get proper results?

**DATABASE STRUCTURE**

```
CREATE TABLE `ft_test` (
  `i_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `i_desc` mediumtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `ft_test`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`i_id`) USING BTREE;
ALTER TABLE `ft_test` ADD FULLTEXT KEY `i_desc` (`i_desc`);

ALTER TABLE `ft_test`
  MODIFY `i_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
COMMIT;
```

**DATABASE DATA**

```
SELECT * FROM ft_test;
+------+-----------+
| i_id | i_desc    |
+------+-----------+
|    1 | test      |
|    2 | test+     |
|    3 | test++    |
|    4 | test +    |
|    5 | test plus |
+------+-----------+
```

TEST #1: **LIKE QUERY**

```
SELECT * FROM ft_test WHERE i_desc LIKE 'test+%';
+------+--------+
| i_id | i_desc |
+------+--------+
|    2 | test+  |
|    3 | test++ |
+------+--------+
```

TEST #2: **FULLTEXT QUERY**

```
SELECT *, MATCH(`i_desc`) AGAINST ('"test+"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS RELEVANCE
    -> FROM `ft_test`
    -> WHERE MATCH(`i_desc`) AGAINST ('"test+"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
    -> ORDER BY RELEVANCE;

+------+-----------+-----------+
| i_id | i_desc    | RELEVANCE |
+------+-----------+-----------+
|    1 | test      |         1 |
|    2 | test+     |         1 |
|    3 | test++    |         1 |
|    4 | test +    |         1 |
|    5 | test plus |         1 |
+------+-----------+-----------+
```

As you can see, **LIKE** query actually returned and sorted results better in this case. I have also tried using quotes for exact match, same results. Adding 'special' characters like 'test\+' didn't help, either. While, FT results are not useless, they are less than perfect, because ordering is not what I expect it to be.

**QUESTION**

Is it actually possible to achieve this and return same results as in LIKE using **FULLTEXT** mode? If yes, how?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you use boolean mode if you do not need the operators?

Comment: It's part of a script, hard coded.

Comment: I'm not sure if + is considered as part of a word. My guess that it is a word delimiter and is hence excluded from the fulltext index and ignored in the search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only index punctuation characters if you define your column as using a collation that treats the characters as normal letters, not punctuation.

There's a manual page that shows steps to do this: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/full-text-adding-collation.html

But since you said your script is hard-coded, I suppose you don't have access to redefine the collation for the column you are searching, or to restart the MySQL server after installing a custom collation definition.

A workaround is to search for the word *without* the punctuation, then add a condition to be applied after finding matching words.

```
SELECT *, MATCH(`i_desc`) AGAINST ('"test"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AS RELEVANCE
FROM `ft_test`
WHERE MATCH(`i_desc`) AGAINST ('"test"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 AND i_desc LIKE 'test+%';
ORDER BY RELEVANCE;
```

It'll use the fulltext index to find rows that match the word, and then the other condition term will filter against that (hopefully small) set of rows for those that have the string with the `+` included.

But again, if you don't have any access to change the SQL query, this is moot.

Comment: Thanks Bill, accepted as answer. Of course, I can change the source code, but I'd avoid it if not really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL full text search does not recognizes special characters. It is meant to seach for word characters only, which `+` is not.

If you want to filter on special characters, `LIKE` is what you need.

Also, with InnoDB, the `+` sign has a special meaning when it is placed *before* the word only, not after. So as it is, your query is actually equivalent to :

```
MATCH(`i_desc`) AGAINST ('"test"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Thanks. I know that part about InnoDB, that's why its MyISAM table, and yes, figured that part by comparing and getting same results as without any special characters at the end. 'Problem' switching to LIKE is that it has to be *managed* somehow from the front-end input (dependding if query contains +, and is that a logical concatenation or part of word?), and that switching complicates search considerably. I accepted Bill's answer above, as it hit the spot.